# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET with IIS express in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

We´ve created a ASP.Net Core Web App and added some controllers. For some reason when I want to run the application, it connects to my local IIS express and the only message that occurs is the following

ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

I don´t try to connect to the port via SSL, so I don´t think it´s a certificate issue.

It doesn´t matter which controller I try to call. For some reason this behaviour appears just on my machine. If I create a new Wep App it works perfectly fine.

I tried the following steps:

- Changed the port number in the web server settings in the project properties
- Uninstalled IIS Express and reinstalled it
- Deleted the hole .vs folder in my project
- Host the web app on my local IIS Server
- Compared the hole project settings with the project settings of a machine, where it runs fine

I´m stuck on this problem for 2 days now and don´t want to reinstall VS2017. Maybe it´s just a little thing which I´ve missed.

Thanks for your replies :)

Comment: Run a report and see if it identifies typical issues https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 3):

The problem was based on my Visual Studio instance. Reinstalling Visual Studio + repairing after this over the VS-installer solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET and you said you tried:

> *Changed the port number in the web server settings in the project properties*

Consider that IIS express reserve ports in the range 44300 to 44399.

I had exatly the same ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when i set IIS Express port out of this range.
The solution was to put port number inside this range. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @Yunnosch I apologize if I was not clear, mine was an answer not a comment and now I am editing the answer to clarify thanks

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."